# equivalent of mcrypt_encrypt in PhpSecLib

Tags: php, mcrypt, phpseclib, php-7.1

I have an old piece of code that's written using `mcrypt` extension and I have to change it to `phpseclib`. But my code doesn't generate the same output as mcrypt function:

Old code:

```
$encryptedText =mcrypt_encrypt(
        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
        $myKey,
        $data ,
        MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
        $myIV
    );
```

My new code:

```
$aes = new \phpseclib\Crypt\AES(\phpseclib\Crypt\AES::MODE_CBC);
$aes->setKey($myKey);
$aes->setIV($myIV);
$aes->disablePadding();
$seclib = $aes->encrypt( $data );
```

but `$encryptedText`  and `$seclib`  are not the same.

Comment: and can you decrypt results with different lib?

Comment: i am not sure but isnt it a default behavior not allowing you (for security) to get same text encrypting it twice

Comment: @RafailAkhmetshin No, I don't decrypt with different libraries. There is a service which requires me to encrypt data with this algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're equating Rijndael with AES, a common misconception.

AES is only a subset of it - Rijndael-128, with the difference between AES variations being only the key size:

- AES-128 is Rijndael-128 with a 128-bit key.
- AES-256 is again Rijndael-128, but with a 256-bit key.

The suffix number in Rijndael variations on the other hand, refers to both key size *and block size*, so of course you cannot get Rijndael-256 by doing AES, as you need a 256-bit block size.

There's a page on the phpseclib docs, which generates sample code after you input the basic variables (cipher, mode, key size, bit size). It outputs the following for [Rijndael, CBC, 256, 256](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/crypt/examples.html#rijndael,cbc,outer,k128,kr256,b256,key,padding,):

```
<?php
include('Crypt/Rijndael.php');
include('Crypt/Random.php');

$cipher = new Crypt_Rijndael(); // could use CRYPT_RIJNDAEL_MODE_CBC
$cipher->setBlockLength(256);
// keys are null-padded to the closest valid size
// longer than the longest key and it's truncated
//$cipher->setKeyLength(256);
$cipher->setKey('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456');
// the IV defaults to all-NULLs if not explicitly defined
$cipher->setIV(crypt_random_string($cipher->getBlockLength() >> 3));

$size = 10 * 1024;
$plaintext = str_repeat('a', $size);

echo $cipher->decrypt($cipher->encrypt($plaintext));
```

I am not sure if the library actually supports this cipher without mcrypt availablity, but it should.

---

I assume you are doing this because mcrypt is being dropped from PHP, and I strongly suggest that you change your strategy.

Even if the above works, it would be quite slow when using a userland PHP implementation of the algorithm (something which is noted in the phpseclib docs), but more importantly - you'll have no other alternatives if this library stops working, is no longer maintained, etc. Non-AES variations of Rijndael are not ubiquitous, and there are more modern algorithms available today anyway (hint: libsodium being added to PHP 7.2).

If I were you, I'd change the algorithm entirely. Of course, that would mean re-encrypting all of the data, but you'll have to do that eventually and now is really the best time to do it.

Comment: I'm encrypting data to be used  by external service which I have to control over it. Other than this, your solution worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. But you should enquire about other options with this third-party service - they would have the exact same problems to deal with.

Comment: @Narf - phpseclib uses OpenSSL if it's available. When mcrypt was available it'd preferentially use that as well before using it's own internal implementation. It's own implementation is only used as a last resort when absolutely no other options are available.

Comment: @neubert Yea, only OpenSSL doesn't give you Rijndael-256 ... :)

Comment: @Narf - oh right - good catch! Yah - Rijndael-256 is pretty non-standard. Whether or not the host ought to be using ChaCha20 vs AES is one thing but AES vs Rijndael with a 256-bit block size isn't much of a debate imho.